# Is $A+uv^T$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. For which condition(s) this matrix is invertible?

$$A + uv^T$$

and find the inverse of this matrix.

---

I tried to take elementary matrices, $I - \alpha xy^T$, to solve this problem, where $\alpha$ is a constant. $(I-\alpha xy^T)^{-1} = I - \beta xy^T$ iff $\beta = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha y^T x - 1}$ where $\alpha y^T x -1 \neq 0$.

If we take $x=(0,0,\ldots, l_{i+1,i},\ldots,l_{n,i})^T$ and $y=e_i=(0,\ldots, 1,\ldots,0)^T$ then we can find a lower triangular matrix like below:

$$L = \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 \ell _{2,1} & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 \ell _{n-1,1} & \ell _{n-1,2} &  & 1 & 0 \\
 \ell _{n,1} & \ell _{n,2} & \cdots & \ell _{n,n-1} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]=I+\ell_1e_1^T + \ldots + \ell_{n-1}e_{n-1}^T$$

But I don't know how to complete ?

Answer (score 4):

By the [Sherman Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), we know that if $A^{-1}$ exists, then $(A + uv^T)^{-1}$ exists whenever $v^TA^{-1}u + 1 \neq 0$.

Otherwise, we have
$$
(A + uv^T)\left((1 + v^TA^{-1}u)A^{-1} - A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}\right) = (1 + v^TA^{-1}u)I = 0
$$
So that $(A + uv^T)$ fails to be invertible.

I'm not sure about the case in which $A$ is not invertible.

Quick observation: if $A$ is not invertible and $(A + uv^T)$ is invertible, then $A$ must have rank $n-1$.